# Remove Back to Back Duplicate Entries from a List using Linq Method Syntax

Tags: c#, linq

I have a List of status changes that may contain a duplicate entries, that I need to filter down removing the duplicates that happened back to back.

Hopefully a couple example lists will demonstrate what I'd like to implement using linq method syntax.

```
Original List with duplicate entries (Id's 2 and 3 are dups)
Id      Date                    OldStatus       NewStatus
=========================================================
1       9/28/2016 10:00:00 AM   Requested       Quoted
2       9/28/2016 10:15:00 AM   Quoted          Rejected
3       9/28/2016 10:15:01 AM   Quoted          Rejected
4       9/28/2016 10:30:00 AM   Rejected        Requested
5       9/28/2016 10:30:00 AM   Requested       Quoted
6       9/28/2016 10:45:00 AM   Quoted          Rejected
7       9/28/2016 10:50:00 AM   Rejected        Requested
8       9/28/2016 10:50:00 AM   Requested       Quoted
9       9/28/2016 10:50:00 AM   Quoted          Purchased

Desired List (Id 3 removed)

Id      Date                    OldStatus       NewStatus
=========================================================
1       9/28/2016 10:00:00 AM   Requested       Quoted
2       9/28/2016 10:15:00 AM   Quoted          Rejected
4       9/28/2016 10:30:00 AM   Rejected        Requested
5       9/28/2016 10:30:00 AM   Requested       Quoted
6       9/28/2016 10:45:00 AM   Quoted          Rejected
7       9/28/2016 10:50:00 AM   Rejected        Requested
8       9/28/2016 10:50:00 AM   Requested       Quoted
9       9/28/2016 10:50:00 AM   Quoted          Purchased
```

I thought about using GroupBy with Date, OldStatus and NewStatus, but I'm concerned that the Date will vary in seconds and I'd still like to exclude 'back to back identical' (OldStatus / NewStatus) entries.

What is an eligant solution to remove these back to back entries using linq method syntax?

Comment: Id 6 is also `OldStatus = Quoted` and `NewStatus = Rejected`. Shouldn't that be removed as well?

Comment: @PiotrWolkowski No, it's not a back to back dup.

Comment: So if the minute value is different then is that considered not a duplicate but if the second value is different then it is?

Comment: It is considered a duplicate if back to back entries Id = n & Id = n + 1 contains identical OldStatus and NewStatus values. Anything other than that use case and it's not a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Aggregate`: add items to an accumulating list if the current item is not equal to the last added item:

```
var result = list.Aggregate(new List<StatusChange>(),
    (lst, i) =>
    {
        var last = lst.LastOrDefault();
        if (last == null
                || (last.Id != i.Id 
                    && last.OldStatus != i.OldStatus
                    && last.NewStatus != i.NewStatus))
        {
            lst.Add(i);
        }
        return lst;
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

In this solution you iterate pairwise and check the pairs. If within a pair both items have the same `OldStatus` and `NewStatus` you add them to the collection of duplicates. After iteration is finished the duplicates are removed from the `statuses` collection:

```
// Find duplicates.
var duplicates = statuses
    .Zip(statuses.Skip(1), (s1, s2) => Tuple.Create(s1, s2))
    .Where(pair => 
        pair.Item1.NewStatus == pair.Item2.NewStatus && 
        pair.Item1.OldStatus == pair.Item2.OldStatus)
    .Select(pair => pair.Item2);

// Remove the duplicates from the original collection of the status changes.
statuses.RemoveAll(s => duplicates.Contains(s));
```

Comment: What is the down vote for? Solution is working and providing the functionality in the question.